# Actionmailer validate maximum email sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I want the user to be able to send no more than 5 emails a day. Is it possible to validate that?

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def contact_email(from_email, body, to_email)
     @body = body

     @user = User.find_by(email: to_email)
     mail(from: from_email, to: to_email, subject: '', cc: from_email)
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def send_mail
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @body = params[:message]

  UserMailer.contact_email(current_user.email, @body, @user.email).deliver_now
end
```

Comment: try this =>

UserMailer.contact_email(current_user.email, @body, @user.email).deliver_now if <PUT_YOUR_LOGIC_HERE>

Comment: @mokariya any idea how logic might look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model `SentMail` with `user_id` and `created_at`.

Modify your `User` model to include `has_many :sent_mails`

Then modify your `send_mail` method as follows.

```
def send_mail
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @body = params[:message]
  if @user.sent_mails.last_day.count < 5
    UserMailer.contact_email(current_user.email, @body, @user.email).deliver_now
    @user.sent_mails.create
  end
end
```

In your `SentMail` model create a scope `last_day` that creates the following query `where(created_at: 24.hours.ago..DateTime.now.utc)`

The `SentMail` model is also a good way to track the emails sent out and would be good if you want to store the state of the email if it was opened, delivered, clicked, etc..

Comment: I tried the above method but `@user.sent_mails.last_day.count` always returns 0

Comment: This is the sql  statement it generates `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "sent_mails" WHERE "sent_mails"."user_id" = $1 AND ("sent_mails"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-11-25 15:18:19.320982' AND '2015-11-26 15:18:19.321052')  [["user_id", 1]]`

Comment: You never create instances of the `SentMail` class for a user. I edited the above answer to add `@user.sent_mails.create` in the method `send_mail` in order to create an instance of `SentMail` whenever an email in sent.

Comment: You can also call `@user.sent_mails.create` in the `contact_email` method in your `UserMailer` class